# Copying an external table schema and partitions metadata from one db to another in hive and presto

Tags: hive, presto, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I want to copy an *external* table's schema and all its partition info from one database to another in Hive and in Presto (AWS Athena). To be clear, I dont want to copy any underlying data - just the metadata.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you confirm if your EMR cluster has AWS Glue integrated with it?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy No, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

In Athena you cloud generate DDL with `SHOW CREATE TABLE database1.tablename` and just execute this statement replacing `database1` to `database2`. It will copy schema but not data and partitions. To populate partitions you should execute [MSCK REPAIR TABLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html) on `database2.tablename`. The same will works for Presto.

If you are unable to populate partitions with `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` you could copy it with Glue API:

```
import boto3
glue = boto3.client('glue')
paginator = glue.get_paginator('get_partitions')
DB_NAME_SRC = 'src'
DB_NAME_DST = 'dst'
TABLE = 'tablename'

partitions = []
for page in paginator.paginate(DatabaseName=DB_NAME, TableName=TABLE):
    for partition in page['Partitions']:
        del partition['DatabaseName']
        del partition['TableName']        
        del partition['CreationTime']        
        partitions.append(partition)
print("Got %d partitions" % len(partitions))
glue.batch_create_partition(DatabaseName=DB_NAME_DST, TableName=TABLE, PartitionInputList=partitions)
```

Comment: In my case partitions are not in hive recognizable format (`../field=value/...`) and are distributed at multiple s3 locations ie. table location is not same as data partitions locations. Hence, I cannot recreate and need a way to copy.

Comment: @GuSuku I've edited the answer, added python script to copy partitions

Answer (score 0):

In PrestoSql you can use `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE` syntax. See https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/create-table.html.

```
CREATE TABLE bigger_orders (
   LIKE orders INCLUDING PROPERTIES
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Does it copy partitions metadata as well? (see my first comment at @shuvalov's answer)